# Multicollinearitytest for binary logistic regression in in R?

Tags: binary, logistic-regression, correlation, multicollinearity

How can multicollinearity be tested for a binary logistic Regression in R?

I tried correlation tables but I dont exactly know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can test for multicollinearity in R:

```
library(car)

# Begin by calculating the correlation matrix for your independent variables
correlation_matrix <- cor(your_data[, c("var1", "var2", "var3")])

# Calculate VIF for your logistic model
vif_values <- vif(your_logistic_model)

# Examine the VIF values. VIF values greater than 5 are often considered indicative of high multicollinearity.
```